# Passing multiple values to parameters from an existing table

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to create a stored procedure which passes values from select statement of joined tables as parameters to another stored procedure inside to create return credit for returned purchase which are assigned in the WHERE clause of joined tables (`@RANO` and `@returndate`). I want to pass many customers (as `@Customer`) from the joined tables to the stored procedure `CreateManCreditHDFromReturn` but it picks the first `@RANO` in the `WHERE` clause of the joined statement!

How can I pass multiple values (like customers, divisions,...) from all RANOs in the where clause of the joined table?

Note: RANO mean return authorization of returned purchase.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateEllieAutoCreditHDFromReturn] 
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ARReason nVarChar(5), 
            @DocumentDate Datetime, 
            @ARDocumentType VarChar(5),
            @TRANSACTIONID INT, 
            @TIMELASTMOD DATETIME, 
            @USERIDLASTMOD nvarchar(5),
            @CompanyCode nVarChar(10),
            @Customer nVarChar(10),
            @Division nVarChar(5),
            @Warehouse nVarChar(10),
            @Salesman1 nVarChar(10),
            @Currency nVarChar(3),
            @ReturnNo int,
            @RANO int,
            @Style nvarchar(15), 

    SELECT @Pkey = @CompanyCode = rh.companycode,
           @Customer = rh.CUSTOMER,
           @Division = rh.DIVISION,
           @Warehouse = rh.WAREHOUSE,
           @Salesman1 = rh.SALESMAN1,
           @Currency = rh.CURRENCY,
           @ReturnNo = rh.returnno, 
           @RANO = rh.RANO
    FROM 
        ReturnDetail rd
    INNER JOIN 
        ReturnHeader rh ON rh.RETURNNO = rd.RETURNNO
    WHERE 
        rh.RETURNDATE >= '2020-03-27 00:00:00' 
        AND rh.RETURNDATE < '2020-03-28 00:00:00' 
        AND rd.RANO IN (79383, 79820) 
        AND rd.ARDOCUMENTNOCOMPANY = 0

    SET @ARReason = 'RM'
    SET @ARDocumentType = 'RCRDT'
    SET @DocumentDate = GETDATE()
    SET @TRANSACTIONID = 0
    SET @TIMELASTMOD = GETDATE()
    SET @USERIDLASTMOD = 'WSchan'
    SET @ReferenceNo = 0

    DECLARE @CurrDocumentNo Int,@CurrDocumentNoCompany Int

    EXEC dbo.CreateManCreditHDFromReturn 
             @CompanyCode,
             @ARReason,
             @Customer,
             @Division,
             @Warehouse,
             @Salesman1,
             @Currency,
             @DocumentDate,
             @ReferenceNo,
             @ARDocumentType,
             @CurrDocumentNo OUTPUT,
             @CurrDocumentNoCompany OUTPUT,
             @TRANSACTIONID, 
             @TIMELASTMOD, 
             @USERIDLASTMOD
END
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign multiple values to scalar variables.  If you are restricted in that you have no access to modify `dbo.CreateManCreditHDFromReturn` then you have to use a cursor or loop and iterate through each record in your query.  The stored procedure is coded to accept one value at a time for its input parameters.

If you have the ability to modify `dbo.CreateManCreditHDFromReturn` then you can update it to accept a table variable, JSON, or XML and then inside that stored procedure you can unpack the input and process it accordingly.

If you have to use a cursor, which I'm guessing is going to be the case, it would look something like this:

```
DECLARE @CompanyCode NVARCHAR(10);
[...and other variables...]

DECLARE RANOCURS CURSOR FOR
SELECT CompanyCode, [...and other fields...]
FROM ReturnDetail rd
INNER JOIN ReturnHeader rh ON rh.RETURNNO = rd.RETURNNO
WHERE rh.RETURNDATE >= '2020-03-27 00:00:00'
AND rh.RETURNDATE< '2020-03-28 00:00:00'
AND rd.RANO IN (79383, 79820)
AND rd.ARDOCUMENTNOCOMPANY = 0;

OPEN RANOCURS;
FETCH NEXT FROM RANOCURS INTO @CompanyCode, [...other variables...]

DECLARE @CurrDocumentNo INT, @CurrDocumentNoCompany INT;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    EXEC dbo.CreateManCreditHDFromReturn
        @CompanyCode ,
        [...other variable parameters...],
        @CurrDocumentNo OUTPUT,
        @CurrDocumentNoCompany OUTPUT;

    [...do something with the return values...]

    FETCH NEXT FROM RANOCURS INTO @CompanyCode, ...[other fields]
END;

CLOSE RANOCURS;
DEALLOCATE RANOCURS;
```